# Move the first element of a list to the end

Tags: java, collections

is there any clever way to do that ? my best way was:

```
object next = list.get(0) ;
list.remove(0) ;
list.add(next) ;
```

if not is there any type of collection that will make that easier ? I don't like the need of a temporary object to store the element i want to move ..

EDIT: I have tested the propositions listed below, with my code:

```
    long starttime = System.nanoTime() ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ntours; i++){
        profit += retrieveGroupsWillPlay(groups, ngroups, limit) ;
    }
    long endtime = System.nanoTime() ;
    System.out.println("Timing: " + (endtime - starttime)) ;
    System.out.println("Profit: " + profit) ;
```

here is the results: (profit: 15, ensure that the result is right for my code)
code:

```
private static int retrieveGroupsWillPlay(ArrayList<Integer> queue,int ngroups, int limit) { 
    int peopleWillPlay = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
        int nextGroup = queue.get(0) ;
        if(limit >= peopleWillPlay + nextGroup) {
            peopleWillPlay += nextGroup ;
            queue.add(nextGroup) ;
            queue.remove(0) ;
        }
        else break ;
    }
    return peopleWillPlay ;
}
```

results:

```
Timing: 23326
Profit: 15
Timing: 22171
Profit: 15
Timing: 22156
Profit: 15
Timing: 22944
Profit: 15
Timing: 22240
Profit: 15
Timing: 21769
Profit: 15
Timing: 21866
Profit: 15
Timing: 22341
Profit: 15
Timing: 24049
Profit: 15
Timing: 22420
Profit: 15
```

code:

```
private static int retrieveGroupsWillPlay(ArrayList<Integer> queue,int ngroups, int limit) { 
    int peopleWillPlay = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
        int nextGroup = queue.get(0) ;
        if(limit >= peopleWillPlay + nextGroup) {
            peopleWillPlay += nextGroup ;
            Collections.rotate(queue, -1) ;
        }
        else break ;
    }
    return peopleWillPlay ;
}
```

results:

```
Timing: 92101
Profit: 15
Timing: 87137
Profit: 15
Timing: 84531
Profit: 15
Timing: 105919
Profit: 15
Timing: 77019
Profit: 15
Timing: 84805
Profit: 15
Timing: 93393
Profit: 15
Timing: 77079
Profit: 15
Timing: 84315
Profit: 15
Timing: 107002
Profit: 15
```

code:

```
private static int retrieveGroupsWillPlay(ArrayList<Integer> queue,int ngroups, int limit) { 
    int peopleWillPlay = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
        int nextGroup = queue.get(0) ;
        if(limit >= peopleWillPlay + nextGroup) {
            peopleWillPlay += nextGroup ;
            queue.add(queue.remove(0)) ;
        }
        else break ;
    }
    return peopleWillPlay ;
}
```

results:

```
Timing: 28079
Profit: 15
Timing: 28994
Profit: 15
Timing: 29525
Profit: 15
Timing: 22240
Profit: 15
Timing: 38326
Profit: 15
Timing: 33742
Profit: 15
Timing: 21500
Profit: 15
Timing: 22714
Profit: 15
Timing: 20939
Profit: 15
Timing: 30157
Profit: 15
```

code:

```
private static int retrieveGroupsWillPlay(LinkedList<Integer> queue,int ngroups, int limit) { 
    int peopleWillPlay = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
        int nextGroup = queue.get(0) ;
        if(limit >= peopleWillPlay + nextGroup) {
            peopleWillPlay += nextGroup ;
            queue.addLast(queue.removeFirst()) ;
        }
        else break ;
    }
    return peopleWillPlay ;
}
```

result:

```
Timing: 31104
Profit: 15
Timing: 42332
Profit: 15
Timing: 36443
Profit: 15
Timing: 31840
Profit: 15
Timing: 31387
Profit: 15
Timing: 32102
Profit: 15
Timing: 31347
Profit: 15
Timing: 30666
Profit: 15
Timing: 32781
Profit: 15
Timing: 32464
Profit: 15
```

code:

```
private static int retrieveGroupsWillPlay(LinkedList<Integer> queue,int ngroups, int limit) { 
    int peopleWillPlay = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
        int nextGroup = queue.get(0) ;
        if(limit >= peopleWillPlay + nextGroup) {
            peopleWillPlay += nextGroup ;
            queue.offer(queue.poll()) ;
        }
        else break ;
    }
    return peopleWillPlay ;
}
```

results:

```
Timing: 35389
Profit: 15
Timing: 34849
Profit: 15
Timing: 43606
Profit: 15
Timing: 41796
Profit: 15
Timing: 51122
Profit: 15
Timing: 59302
Profit: 15
Timing: 32340
Profit: 15
Timing: 35654
Profit: 15
Timing: 34586
Profit: 15
Timing: 35479
Profit: 15
```

Comment: A better structure for doing what? What are you trying to accomplish? Also, what kind of list? ArrayList, LinkedList? Performance may vary...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but here goes:

If you're using something like an `ArrayList`, you can do:

```
list.add(list.remove(0));
```

Please keep in mind that `remove` from an ArrayList runs in linear time, that is, `O(N)`, so that is extremely inefficient.

In case you can choose the type of List, you probably want a `LinkedList`, that implementes the `Dequeue` interface, so it would allow you to do something like:

```
list.offer(list.poll());
```

Both `offer` and `poll` are operations done in constant time.

If you want to use a builtin from the `Collections` class, you can do as @dasblinkenlight suggested and use `Collections.rotate(list, -1);` (adding it here for completeness).

Answer (score 25):

You can use `Collections.rotate` for that:

```
Collections.rotate(list, -1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a temp variable just write:

```
list.add(list.remove(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a [dequeu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque) (short for double ended queue).

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is:

`list.add(list.remove(0))`

which is the most elegant way, I believe.
You could alternatively use

`Collections.swap(list.get(0), list.get(list.size()-1))`

however that will change position of another element (the last one). You could also use `Collections.rotate(list, -1)`, however rotating the list could mean moving all of its elements (it depends on List implementation I guess) and that might not be efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure, but may be `Collections.rotate` behave differently depending on the type of list, if it's a linked list I think it will just take the first one and link it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [**LinkedList#addLast()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29) method.

```
list.add(next) ;     
list.addLast(list.removeFirst());
```