# How can I update the position of an item inside of a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a feature to a To-Do list that causes a "checked" item to go to the bottom of the the list. I'm using an `ArrayList` to hold the items which are organized using a `RecyclerView` so I know that key will be to update the position but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm confused how you'd move everything up by one and then put the checked item in the last position so that it's at the bottom of the list.

This is how I'm doing the checking and unchecking of the boxes:

```
taskCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.taskCheckBox.isChecked())
                {
                    bucketItem.setSelected(false);
                    holder.taskCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    bucketItem.setSelected(true);
                    holder.taskCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know what I'd add to update the position and I'm still confused by how I always know what the "bottom" is because there isn't a fixed number of item in the list.

Comment: Have a look at this [ink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566118/move-the-first-element-of)a-list-to-the-end]. This explains how to move an item to the end of the ArrayList. It's just am remove and add operation on this list. Maybe you have to notify your view that the data is changed

Comment: @ZeusNet Thanks for the link! That helps out a lot. Can you expand on the Android stuff you said? This is my first Android project ever so I'm still learning the lingo.

Comment: The thing is that you are changing the data of your view and therefore the view should get updated as well. For this pupose the adapter of your RecycleView has some methods to notify about this. As example there is a [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) method. But the method [notifyItemMoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemMoved(int,int)) could also be a good choice for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Android team added a support for this kind of actions. Check out DiffUtils:
https://github.com/mrmike/DiffUtil-sample

In a nutshell, you only need to provide a proper data set, and let the library figure out what changed.

If you still want to do this manually, you'll need to do something like this:

1. On click, update the underlying model to have proper selected state
2. Reorder that item to a proper place in a list. (list.remove(position) and then list.add(item) perhaps)
3. Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter. (or even better notifyRangeChanged(from, to)